# Pairing truncated character into a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a chr[1:10] truncated data and each line is organized in such way and some rows don't have the same length:

```
    [1] "\nA   B   C   D   E"
    [2] "\n1       3   4   5"
    [3] "\nF   G   H"
    [4] "\n6   7   8"
```

Here's an updated version of my question

```
   line.1 <- c("A   B   C   D   E")
   line.2 <- c("1       3   4   5")

   line <- rbind(line.1, line.2)

   line <- data.frame(line)

                        line
    line.1 A   B   C   D   E
    line.2 1   3   4   5
```

So, my desired output should be:

```
          V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 
   Line.1  A   B   C   D   E
   Line.2  1       3   4   5
```

I can't quite figure out how to split it into different columns with the extra space in between being counted as one value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
# Build the character vector
x <- c("\nA   B   C   D   E", "\n1       3   4   5", "\nF   G   H", "\n6   7   8")

# Remove the new line characters
x <- sub("\n", "", x)

# Select every other element of the character vector as column 1
Col1 <- paste(x[c(T, F)], collapse = '   ')
Col1 <- strsplit(Col1, '   ')[[1]]

# Do the same for column 2
Col2 <- paste(x[c(F, T)], collapse = '   ')
Col2 <- strsplit(Col2, '   ')[[1]]

# Combine them in a data frame
data.frame(Col1, Col2)
#   Col1 Col2
# 1    A    1
# 2    B     
# 3    C    3
# 4    D    4
# 5    E    5
# 6    F    6
# 7    G    7
# 8    H    8
```

The use of `strsplit` is what splits the values into different columns:

```
> strsplit(line.2, '   ')[[1]]
[1] "1"  ""   " 3" "4"  "5"
```

So to combine both lines as a dataframe, you can do:

```
data.frame(rbind(strsplit(line.1, '   ')[[1]], strsplit(line.2, '   ')[[1]]))
```

Comment: Sorry about the unclear description, here's an update of my question.

Comment: my actual data looks like this 

"Stage #...Date..........................Linked Zone                                                           Top Depth (ftKB)........Bottom Depth (ftKB).....Btm - Top (ft)..........Shot Density (shots/ft) "

I am using the comma to show the whitespace in between. So when I apply your method above, it creates multiple " " in between. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: ...why didn't you just post your actual data to start with? You can get just the first few rows with `head(df)`. Anyway you can replace the `'   '` with any set of characters that you want to split your columns on.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to scrap the pdf forms into a data frame but there are missing information in some of the columns for some while others are filled up. So I can't really simulate the situation here.